# Sound problems in Loki (dummy output) alsa not loading modules

Tags: release-loki, sound

I don't have any sound, only dummy output which doesn't work, and following the Ubuntu guide for troubleshooting sound, I get stuck at loading the modules.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

(This is the guide I'm trying to follow)

To preface this, I have had sound working before on fresh install and it seemed to stop working when I shut my laptop lid. And in my quest to fix the issue, I have updated to kernel 4.18.8 using `ukuu` which appears to work fine other than the sound still not working.

So, when I get to step 4 of the guide, I get no soundcard found.
Then, when I go to check if the modules are installed (step 5 of the guide), I get a normal result.

However, using `alsa` info to give me an output, it appears to not have any 
modules actually loaded.

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=d1320e6df212a41f4dccda8b33ff5fe13c4adc86

That is the output of `alsainfo` as suggested by a number of forums for sound troubles. via this link:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo

Strangely, to add to this, I tried `sudo alsa force-reload`
and I do actually get an output:

```
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-soc-skl snd-soc-skl-ipc snd-soc-sst-ipc snd-soc-sst-dsp snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-acpi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-dummy snd-seq-oss snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-soc-skl snd-soc-skl-ipc snd-soc-sst-ipc snd-soc-sst-dsp snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-acpi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-dummy snd-seq-oss snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.
```

Which is strange, because if there are no modules loaded, what is it unloading and loading...

(Maybe that's just me being a noob, but that seems odd).

Would greatly appreciate help.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me like this
cd into

> /etc/modprobe.d
> edit the alsa.conf
> `sudo nano alsa.conf`

```
add the following line to the options section
```

> options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0

cd onto

> /usr/share/alsa-base

```
using sudo
```

> ./alsa-info.sh

the ** out of that file. and it updates. im sure you have already been installing all the software already. try it in reverse otherwise. and `LOGOUT`.

Answer (score 0):

If sound works after `sudo alsa force-reload`
use `alsa-info.sh` again to see working configuration

If modprobe options for snd_hda_intel are changed from:

> snd_hda_intel: probe_mask index=1
>
> snd_hda_intel: model=auto

You may be able to apply those changes in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

If ALSA can identify the correct audio codec, may be an appropriate model option listed [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/sound/hd-audio/models.rst)

Comment: It seems to be working now after dumping the pulse config. alsa-info now outputs: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=edfe85df50ee64c180051a6cb410eff3c27e9ba9

Comment: I note that both of those modprobe options no longer present. Presume you may have had update for Pulseaudio to cause loss of sound? update sometimes needs home folder cookie reset `rm ~/.config/pulse/cookie`